# Reshaping & Selecting Pandas from Pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, multiple-columns

## Problem

I have the following data frame (note values are just to show format):

```
>>> print df
           Country  Public Private
Date                              
2013-01-17      BE            3389
2013-01-17      DK    4532     681
2013-02-21      DE    2453    1752
2013-02-21      IE            5143
2013-02-21      ES    8633     353
2013-03-21      FR             262
2013-03-21      LT             358
```

I would like to pivot it to show the following format:

```
Country        Country1          Country2        
           Private  Public   Private  Public                                  
Date                                                           
2013-01-17     681     353       262   5143 
2013-02-21     149     176       124   1757 
2013-03-21     149     176       124   1757
```

## Generate Problem

This will generate the problem

```
import pandas as pd

data =[['2013-01-17',  'BE',1000,3389],
    ['2013-01-17',  'IE',5823, 681],
    ['2013-01-17',  'FR',1000,1752],
    ['2013-02-17',  'IE',1000,5143],
    ['2013-02-17',  'FR',1000, 353],
    ['2013-03-17',  'FR',1000, 262],
    ['2013-03-17',  'BE',1000, 358]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Date','Country','Public','Private']).set_index('Date')
```

## Attempts

The best I can manage is getting Country and the Data Description the wrong way round:

```
>>> print df.pivot(index=df.index,columns='Country').fillna('')
           Public        Private
Country        AT    BE       DE    DK 
Date                                
2013-01-17   1000  1000     1000  1000
2013-02-21   1000  1000     1000  1000
2013-03-21   1000  1000     1000  1000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use swap levels to swap them. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html

df.pivot(index=df.index,columns='Country').fillna('').swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sortlevel(axis=1)

Comment: Please can you make your answer clearer? any example code?
`df.pivot(index=df.index,columns='Country').fillna('').swaplevel(0,1)` gives me an error as does `df.pivot(index='Country',columns='Country').fillna('')`